# Using FPDF with composer autoloading

Tags: php, namespaces, composer-php, fpdf

I can use the FPDF class if I require the right file from my library:

```
<?php namespace MyNamespace;

require_once '../../../vendor/setasign/fpdf/fpdf.php';
// use FPDF;

$pdf = new \FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
$pdf->Cell(40,10,'Hello World!');
$pdf->Output();
```

Note: the fpdf.php file is not namespaced.

Composer should be autoloading this file for me. A snippet from my autoload_classmap.php generated by composer:

```
// autoload_classmap.php @generated by Composer

$vendorDir = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
$baseDir = dirname($vendorDir);

return array(
    'FPDF' => $vendorDir . '/setasign/fpdf/fpdf.php',
    'File_Iterator' => $vendorDir . '/phpunit/php-file-iterator/src/Iterator.php',
```

Another library, phpunit is loading fine.

How can I autoload the FPDF library with composer and use: `use FPDF;`?

Comment: In case anyone wants to load the FPDF with composer: `"require": { "setasign/fpdf": "^1.8" }`

Comment: Hmm. autoload_classmap.php should be the authoritative source for libraries autoloaded via classmapping. The only thing I'd suggest is running `composer dump-autoload`. But I'm pretty sure all that does is refresh the autoload_classmap.php file and will be useless (because FPDF is already listed there).

Answer (score 1):

I neglected to require the `autoload.php` file from the `vendors` folder. Because the function is global I don't even have to add `use FPDF;`.

```
<?php namespace MyNamespace;

require_once '../../../vendor/autoload.php';

$pdf = new \FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
$pdf->Cell(40,10,'Hello World!');
$pdf->Output();
```

Phpunit was working because phpunit is being accessed from the commandline and I had phpunit set up to include the `autoload.php` file.

I hope this helps someone else too. It's a little frustrating when you spend hours on something seemingly simple like this.